# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar preg_replace a preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, php7

Estoy intentando sustituir la función `preg_replace` con `preg_replace_back` para PHP7, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Éste es el código original:

```
function sd_code_filter($content_text) {
        $content_text = preg_replace('!(<pre.*?>)(.*?)</pre>!ise', " '$1' .  stripslashes( str_replace(array('<','>'),array('<','>'),'$2') )  . '</pre>' ", $content_text);
        return $content_text;
```

Intenté algo así, pero me sale aun el error, o que estaré haciendo mal:

```
function sd_code_filter($content_text) {
        $content_text = preg_replace_callback( '!(<pre.*?>)(.*?)</pre>!ise',
            function ($matches){
                $output = $matches[1].  stripslashes( str_replace(array('<','>'),array('<','>'),$matches[2]) )  . '</pre>';
                return $output;
            }, 
            $content_text
        );
        return $content_text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo era de cambiar `!ise` por `!is`, no me había fijado.

El modificador `e` se consideró obsoleto a partir de PHP 5.5 y se eliminó en PHP 7 como se indica en la [documentación de PHP sobre los modificadores de patrones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval).